# Build custom post type single page by shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

We know , we can create custom post type's single page by forming a php file single-$posttype.php

But I need to make a single page of a custom post type by shortcode that I mean , I will put a shortcode in a page which will show single page content on it.

Is it possible?

Comment: You could probably have the shortcode call [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Comment: Its not a Question type Title. Please, remember it everytime.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this plugin for your requirement: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-content-shortcodes/